# get parallel ssh output in order but use parallelism

Tags: ssh, parallel-processing

With `parellel-ssh -i -h hosts.ini "uptime"` I can get the uptime from all hosts in `hosts.ini`. But they appear in order of the batches and first answers. I would like to have the result ordered like in hosts.ini.

I can use `-p 1` to get this, but then there is no more parallelism and the process ist very slow. Is there a way to get both with paraellel-ssh options? Of course I could order my hosts.ini AND the result by alphabetical or whatever. But in my case, the order in hosts.ini depends on another source.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Parallel:

```
parallel -k -a hosts.ini ssh {} uptime
```

(as long as your lines are [user@]host).